# app has stopped in my phone due to TextView

Tags: android

when i try it in my phone , text is not coming and the app will stopped .......anyone can help??
the debug can't find the error and the other frame have no problem, except this .
the problem is coming from TextView ...... if I cut the lines the error won't come

```
 package com.example.soo;

  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
     import android.widget.TextView;

     public class Res2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView ans3;
 TextView ans;
 TextView ans2;
 TextView ans4;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ans3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
     ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     ans2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
     ans4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.res2);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.res2, menu);
    return true;
}
public void mai()
{
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    double r1 =bundle.getDouble("some_key");
    double r2 =bundle.getDouble("some_key2");
    int bet =bundle.getInt("bet");
    double a2x1;
    double a2x;
     a2x1=r1*r2*bet;
     a2x=a2x1+(r1+r2)*bet;      
     String aa="if u both match wins: "+ a2x1;
     String aa2="if u both match wins: "+a2x;
     String aa3="if first match wins: "+(r1*bet);
     String aa4="if second match wins: "+(r2*bet);
             ans.setText(aa);
             ans2.setText(aa2);
             ans3.setText(aa3);
             ans4.setText(aa4);
   }
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Debug won't find it?  No, you don't know how to use debug ;)  Post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: his setContentView() call is AFTER the findViewById() calls. That's the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Change your oncreate() method

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.res2);
    ans3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ans2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    ans4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
}
```

Comment: error went..... but the text("if first match wins:" ) is not showing up in the TextView

Comment: Where do you call `mai()`?

Answer (score 0):

it will help you

change the position of your

### setContentView(R.layout.res2);

instead of your coding put these lines in the oncreate

```
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.res2);
     ans3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
     ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     ans2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
     ans4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
```

Comment: error went..... but the text("if first match wins:" ) is not showing up in the TextView